# Sensor Performance Analysis

Tags: sensor, temperature, data, analysis

I've recently built a temperature sensor and have been testing it against a reference thermometer in several different scenarios/environments/temperature ranges.

My question is, how do I analyse my data to show my sensor is accurate to `x`degrees or how good/bad its performance is. 
I have a list of reference temperatures readings against my own temperatures readings; I've calculated the difference between the two and calculated the mean difference and standard deviation. Is this enough to say, my sensor is accurate to, for example, 0.2degrees or is there any other data analysis techniques I could use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It vastly depends on what kind of sensor you are using and what you are going to use your analysis for.

Some sensors have a linear output while others do not. If you're comparing accuracy for a linear sensor with a non linear sensor you definitely cannot produce a flat accuracy answer.

The test should reflect your end purpose and also the actual output form of the sensor. Is it a digital sensor giving you a direct output in spi/i2c? Is it giving you a voltage output and you're measuring with an ADC? This is important to quantify any source for error/discrepancy.

Comment: I've implemented a thermistor in a voltage divider circuit, so I'm measuring the voltage with an ADC and converting that into a temperature.

Comment: So thermistors are not linear, (if you havent already) find an equation which relates voltage to temperature. Then you can compare the difference in temperature using the methods you described. Unless you have a specific application in mind it is fine to just say how much the error is. If you want to go a further step find the error for different temperature ranges, you should find that it varies.